# Monomorphism between ${\rm GL}(1,4)$ and ${\rm GL}(2,2)$ that corresponds to the inclusion of $A_3$ in $S_3$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, permutations, monomorphisms

I am currently solving as many exercises as possible from General linear groups and special linear groups because I am not good in this part of algebra.

The question here is to construct one such monomorphism and I have also given as a hint that the field $\mathbb{F}_4$ can be written as $\{0,1,a,a^2\}$ where $a+1=a^2$ and $y+y=0$  for all $y\in\mathbb{F}_4$.

Is there any way to construct such a monomorphism?

This part that it has to correspond to the inclusion of $A_3$ in $S_3$ troubles me a lot.

I don't know how to start even because I was more used to showing that something is a homomorphism or an automorphism, but now when I have to think about how to construct something like this it gets a bit too difficult.

Comment: How many elements these groups have? Enumerate them.

Comment: Look at the vector space $V$ of dimension $1$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$. It is also a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ [check this if you have doubts]. In fact it has dimension $2$ as $\mathbb{F}_2$ space [check this]. Also every $1--1$ onto $\mathbb{F}_4$-linear mapping $V\to V$  is also a $1--1$ onto $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear mapping $V\to V$: so you get your embedding.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** First ignore the hint, and consider the basis $1,a$ in $F_4=\{0,1,a,a^2\}$ over $F_2=\{0,1\}$, and calculate the matrices of  multiplications by $1,a,a^2$.

Finally, find an isomorphism $GL_2(F_2)\cong S_3$ and verify that the image of the above embedding corresponds to $A_3$ to justify the 'hint'.